# Loading Images To JComboBox

Tags: java, image, swing, jcombobox, imageicon

I am loading 50 images to JComboBox which I render with custom renderer that extends the DefaultListCellRenderer. Everything works except performance because my app uses 400+ MB of RAM.

Here is my renderer:

```
public class ImageRenderer extends DefaultListCellRenderer{

private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
        boolean cellHasFocus) {



    if(value!=null) {
        setText(((File)value).getName());
        setIcon(getScaledImageIcon(this, ((File)value)));
    }

    if(isSelected) {
        setBackground(Color.DARK_GRAY);
        setForeground(Color.WHITE);
    }
    else {
        setBackground(Color.WHITE);
        setForeground(Color.BLACK);
    }

    return this;
}

public ImageIcon getScaledImageIcon(JLabel label, File file) {
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(file.getAbsolutePath());
    Image img = image.getImage();
    Image newImage = img.getScaledInstance(30, 30, Image.SCALE_SMOOTH);
    return new ImageIcon(newImage);
}
```

}

Here is the code that adds Files to JComboBox:

```
public void loadOffers() {
    SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() {

        @Override
        public void run() {
            File[] offers = new File(workingDir.getAbsolutePath() + "/offers").listFiles();
            addedOffers.removeAllElements();
            for(int i=0;i<offers.length;i++)
                addedOffers.addElement(offers[i]);
            offersBox.setRenderer(new ImageRenderer());
        }
    });
}
```

Here is how it looks:
[image]
Luckily my PC has 16GB of RAM but that is not the point. Please help.

Comment: I see that you resize images to 30x30 pixels. What is their real size and tried to resize them in advance (if they are too large)?

Comment: they are large, some are 800x600 and so...

Comment: Reduce them in advance to the desired size. If you need to show them in higher quality in the app, use two versions (original and thumbnail).

Comment: but those 50 images are totaling 18MB in their original sizes, and my app uses 400MB to display them.

Comment: the system uses memory and resizing, though. as far as I know, the virtual machine reserves memory when and should not mark it as free when the application does not use it.
just test it by eliminating the need for resizing.

Comment: you can try and cache the loaded images. so you will not have to create them again and again on demand.

Answer (score 0):

```
setIcon(getScaledImageIcon(this, ((File)value)));
```

The problem is that you are scaling the images every time the popup of the combo box is displayed. The scaled image should be stored as part of the object in the model.

So you create a custom Object that contains two properties:

1. scaled icon
2. text

Then your custom renderer simply displays the two values.

```
@Override
public Component getListCellRendererComponent(JList<?> list, Object value, int index, boolean isSelected,
        boolean cellHasFocus) {


    if(value!=null) {
        CustomObject o = (CustomObject)value;
        setText(o.getName());
        setIcon(o.getScaledIcon());
    }

    ...
```

Comment: Still not working. The part:offer.setImageIcon(new ImageIcon(offers[i].getPath())); produces 400MB ram. However when i change to offer.setImageIcon(new ImageIcon("D:/alucia.png")); it works just fine. But all offers have same image in that case :(

Comment: That was not the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

> but those 50 images are totaling 18MB in their original sizes, and my app uses 400MB to display them

PNG files are compressed. If they take 18 MB on disk, that only means that there are many identical colours that compress very well.

In order to display them, they will need to be uncompressed so that each and every pixel has RGB values (red, green, blue). Thus, the image will use `width*height*3` bytes in memory.

If you need those 50 images in 30x30 pixels, you should resize them in advance and they will need a bit more than 50*30*30*3 = 135 kB in memory. Whereas 50 images at 800x600 will need at least 50*800*600*3 = 72 MB.